# Linking GSL in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, gsl

I have a code with multiple files, that uses the GSL Library. When I compile the code through the terminal with the command

```
g++ main.cpp -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -o Exec
```

This compiles and gives the correct output and no errors.
However, when I try and build the code in CLion I get the error

```
undefined reference to `gsl_rng_uniform'
```

I have linked the various .cpp files in my code through the CMakeLists.txt, but I think, I have to something similar to the flags to link to GSL.
My CMakeLists.txt file is as follows currently (only the .cpp files are included in the source files, not the .h files):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Unitsv1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp
                 transition.cpp
                 random.cpp)
add_executable(Unitsv1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I'm very new to C++, and can't seem to find any answers online.
Thanks

Comment: Append this command to your CMakeLists.txt
 target_link_libraries(Unitsv1  gsl)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: gotta make sure it's in the search path, though, too.  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't linked in the GSL libraries, so the linker won't find any of the symbols it provides. Something like this should get you most of the way there:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Unitsv1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)   # See below (1)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp
                 transition.cpp
                 random.cpp)
add_executable(Unitsv1 ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)    # See below (2)
target_link_libraries(Unitsv1 GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)
```

If your code uses C++11, then you need the line at (1) to ensure you actually get C++11 support. Without `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES`, the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` variable acts only as "Use it if it is available, or fall back to the closest standard the compiler can provide". You can find a detailed write-up [here](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/) if you're curious.

The more important part for your question is at (2). The `find_package()` command looks for the GSL libraries, etc. and makes them available as import targets `GSL::gsl` and `GSL::gslcblas`. You then use `target_link_libraries()` to link your executable to them as shown. The CMake documentation explains how the `find_package()` side of things works in plenty of detail:

- Start here: [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)
- Specifics for GSL: [`FindGSL` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGSL.html)
- Linking: [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)

Comment: So I had to add

    include_directories(${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
but then it worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: That's odd. The `GSL::gsl` import target already has its `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property set to the contents of `GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS`, so that shouldn't have been necessary.