# CMakeLists.txt Access GSL Library C

Tags: c, cmake

Trying to use GSL (Ubuntu 18.04) with CMake.

Installed it according to their INSTALL file:

"sudo sh configure && sudo make && sudo make install"

My Folder Structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

The GSL header files are located in /gsl-2.5/gsl/

My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(neuronalnetwork C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(neuronalnetwork main.c)


include_directories(gsl-2.5/gsl)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(gsl-2.5)
target_link_libraries(main.c gsl)
```

Error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "main.c" which is not built by
  this project.
```

If adding target_link_libraries(neuronalnetwork gsl) I get this error:

**Update New Error:**

```
/opt/clion/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/filip/Projekte/neuronalnetwork/cmake-build-debug --target neuronalnetwork -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target neuronalnetwork
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/neuronalnetwork.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable neuronalnetwork
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ctrmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zswap'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zsymm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cgeru'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ctrsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sgemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_srotg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zgemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cdotu_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dznrm2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ddot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_csymm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cher2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zdotu_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sdot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sdsdot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cgerc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_scnrm2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ctrmm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_strmm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zcopy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dsyrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cherk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zherk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zher'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ztrmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_drotmg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dswap'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_scopy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_scasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_drotg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zdotc_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_caxpy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zsyr2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ssyr2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_csyr2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ztrsm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ctrsm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ssymm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cdotc_sub'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zher2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_saxpy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_idamax'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_snrm2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dsdot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cher'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dger'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cher2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dzasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dsyr2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ssyrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_strmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cgemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dsymv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_srotm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sswap'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dtrmv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_isamax'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zhemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zaxpy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dcopy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sasum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dsyr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_strsm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_drot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ztrsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_izamax'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ssymv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_chemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zgeru'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dtrsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_sger'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_srot'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dsymm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ztrmm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zdscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zher2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ssyr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dtrmm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zgerc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_csscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dsyr2k'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_chemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dnrm2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_drotm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_icamax'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zgemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zhemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cgemv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ssyr2'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_strsv'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dscal'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dgemm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_srotmg'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_dtrsm'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_ccopy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_zsyrk'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_cswap'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_daxpy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so: undefined reference to `cblas_csyrk'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Suggestions in other questions didn't work

Comment: Name of the executable **target** is `neuronalnetwork` (the first argument for `add_executable` command). This name should be used with `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Works BUT new Error Code! @Tsyvarev Updated my Post.

Comment: Well, looks like you need to link your executable with `cblas` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking GSL in Cmakelists.txt in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821615/linking-gsl-in-cmakelists-txt-in-clion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new error message tells you that the blas library, is not found; see the [gsl example](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/usage.html#linking-programs-with-the-library) for the linker flags you need to add.

For more advanced details on how to work with GSL through CMake, look at the [`FindGSL.cmake`](https://github.com/cryos/eigen/blob/master/cmake/FindGSL.cmake) file of the eigen project.

More generally, one would usually use GSL as an external dependency, are you sure you want to include it in your code?

**EDIT** from the comments, you should use GSL as an external dependency, just install it on your system using your linux package manager (look for gsl and make sure to get the header files)

Then, copy the `FindGSL.cmake` file of eigen, copy it somewhere, then, as they do here run, in your CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(GSL)
include_directories(${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Note that if you want to put the .cmake in a specific directory, you will need to tell CMake where to look for it using

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/where/you/put/the/file/)
```

**EDIT 2:**

To make it more explicit, here is the full code you need:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(neuronalnetwork C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
find_package(GSL)

add_executable(neuronalnetwork main.c)
target_include_directories(neuronalnetwork PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(neuronalnetwork ${GSL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I want to implement a neuronalnetwor in C and I want to use a matrix library. Pretty new to C  so I just downloaded it from their site

Comment: then just search for `libgsl` (and potentially `libgsl-dev`) in your package manager and install it, then you can just use eigen's FindGSL to get its location in the system

Comment: So when do I need to implement it like this? @Silmathoron

Comment: sorry, implement what like what?

Comment: You suggest using it as an external dependency (with libgsl and libgsl-dev).


You can also do it by compiling and importing it with cmake.


When do I choose which path?

Comment: see edit, you do not chose the path, the code in FindGSL.cmake does the lookup

Comment: So where to copy the findgsl.cmake https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kitware/CMake/master/Modules/FindGSL.cmake?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184619/discussion-between-silmathoron-and-filip).

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and help! Fixed!