# CMake can't find GSL library

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, gsl, macos-mojave

I am trying to build my C++17 project using GSL under GCC on MacOS Mojave 10.14.3. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(bigkernel)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/g++-8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -std=c++17 -mpopcnt -L/usr/local/lib")

include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Include /usr/local/include)
add_executable(bigkernel
    Include/CapacityEvaluator.h
    SRC/CapacityEvaluator.cpp
    #other executables)
find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(bigkernel GSL:gsl GSL:gslcblas)
```

However, each time following error occurs:

```
ld: library not found for -lGSL:gsl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [bigkernel] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/bigkernel.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bigkernel.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [bigkernel] Error 2
```

What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I tried to follow recommendations given here: [Linking GSL in Cmakelists.txt in CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821615/linking-gsl-in-cmakelists-txt-in-clion), but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Are you sure about the `GSL:` prefix?

Comment: It should be `GSL::` instead of `GSL:`

Comment: @drescherjm thank you, it works!

Comment: Closing as a typo graphical error. You can delete if you want.