# how to include an external library with cmake when find_package() fails?

Tags: cmake, conda

I'm new to cmake.

I've installed **gsl library** with **conda**.
I first used `find_package(gsl REQUIRED)` but
**cmake** didn't find neither "Findgsl.cmake" nor "gslConfig.cmake".
So I tried to use `find_library()` and `find_path()` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

project(projTEST)

find_library(GSL_LIBRARY gsl "/home/albator/miniconda3/envs/test/lib/" REQUIRED)
find_path(GSL_INCLUDE_DIR gsl "/home/albator/miniconda3/envs/test/include/")

message(STATUS "gsl include dirs: " ${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(STATUS "gsl lib dirs: " ${GSL_LIBRARY})

set(SRCS
main.cpp)

set(HDRS
)

add_executable(test ${SRCS} ${HDRS} )
set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX )
target_link_libraries(test ${GSL_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${GSL_INCLUDE_DIR})

install(TARGETS test 
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

but when I compile `#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>` is not found...

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have the mentioned CMake files on your system? You may need to point Cmake to that path first.

Comment: @Botje In fact I haven't found the "Findgsl.cmake" nor "gslConfig.cmake" on my system. So I tried directly to link the library and the headers files...

Comment: FindGSL.cmake has been part of the CMake distribution since CMake 3.2. Are you sure it is not packaged with CMake? Or are you running an ancient CMake?

Comment: @Botje I use cmake version 3.16.3. I haven't found any file .cmake delivered with the gsl library. And I reinstalled gsl with conda but none .cmake file appeared...

Comment: No, FindGSL.cmake should be part of your **CMake** installation.

Comment: @Botje You're right ! I've found FindGSL.cmake in  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules. But find_package() is not supposed to find it automatically ? I forgot to precise that I use Cmake with vscode. I don't know if it makes a difference...

Comment: Did you actually write `find_package(gsl REQUIRED)` or did you write `find_package(GSL REQUIRED)` ?  Linux systems are case-sensitive, so is CMake.

Comment: @Botje I used `find_package(gsl REQUIRED)`. With `find_package(GSL REQUIRED)` I have another error:   ``` CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
 Could NOT find GSL (missing: GSL_CBLAS_LIBRARY) (found version "") ```

Comment: That means CMake was running the FindGSL.cmake script but failed to find GSL. The hints on the [linked reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGSL.html) page (thanks @Tsyvarev!) does mention that should set GSL_ROOT_DIR.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for your help. find_package seems working now. But I 've still a problem when I compile : the header file #include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h> is not found...

Comment: Make sure to `target_link_libraries(test GSL::gsl)` to properly configure the header and library paths.

Comment: @Botje I do the same like in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821615/linking-gsl-in-cmakelists-txt] but without success...

Comment: Ask a new question then, with your code and your error message.

Comment: @Botje it works! I delete and rebuild everything. Thanks a lot for your help!